# RxJava within Android ListView - How to Track Observables for Each Row?

Tags: android, listview, rx-java, rx-android

We are using a custom `ListViewAdapter` to build out a list in our Android app. Each row in the `ListView` has a button. We are also using a custom `Observable<Object>` class as our observable.

In the `ListViewAdapter`, in the `getView(...)` method, I am creating the observer for the given row's button, then I add that observer to a `PublishSubject` in the Adapter.

Where I'm getting stuck is that when the list is scrolled and Views start getting recycled:

- How do I remove a given row's Button Observer from the `PublishSubject`
- How do I track if a given row's button has already been added to the `PublishSubject`?
- Anything else I need to be accounting for here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subscribe/unsubscribe to your observable when your item view is attach/detach, example from `RecyclerView` `ViewHolder`

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnAttachStateChangeListener
{

    private Disposable mDisposable;

    MyViewHolder ( View itemView )
    {
        super( itemView );
        itemView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener( this );
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow( View v )
    {
        if( mDisposable != null )
            mDisposable.dispose( );
        mDisposable = myObservable.subscribe();

    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow( View v )
    {
        if( mDisposable != null )
            mDisposable.dispose( );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you creating `myObservable` in `onBindViewHolder()`? I'm not clear where `myObservable` is coming from or how it's being accessed from within `MyViewHolder`

Comment: You create it wherever you want